# Staying vs staying at

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Should I add "at" in the following sentence?

> I drove to the hotel my friend was staying (at).

Should I add "at"? Why or why not?

I found both versions on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=OMH&biw=1855&bih=954&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02NlyUCcQuKOhcJ7xwWpxFfA1B9mw%3A1602411905414&ei=gd2CX4fzGKSSr7wPisyYwAQ&q=%22the%20hotel%20I%20was%20staying%22&oq=%22the%20hotel%20I%20was%20staying%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10834.12182.0.12281.9.9.0.0.0.0.139.611.6j2.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.zS7Cobk67l4):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would add it; you’ll notice that the vast majority of your google search results are either “staying at” or “staying in”.

You could omit it, by adding “where”:

> I drove to the hotel where my friend was staying.

I can’t give an academic reason for this, but consider the following:

> I drove to the hotel my friend was managing.

Your friend is managing the hotel.

I’m your example, your friend is not “staying” the hotel (a nonsensical statement), your friend is “staying **at**” the hotel.

Comment: I think the reason would be that "where" already carries with it the notion of "at" (or "to").  "Where" can be replaced with "at which".  Btw, the OP's Google search *did* find one or two examples where there was neither "at" nor "in", e.g. "A young man working at the hotel I was staying invited me to go snow skiing on nearby slopes".  This doesn't sound right to me though - perhaps it is an American colloquialism.  Another example is "He sent one of his guys to pick me up from the hotel I was staying".

Comment: @rjpond - Thanks, I’ve adjusted my answer to not claim “all search results”.

Comment: @rjpond: Your example *A young man working at the hotel I was staying invited me to go snow skiing on nearby slopes* is quite simply ungrammatical without either ***where*** before ***I was staying***, or ***at*** after it. Less articulate speakers might be more likely to make that particular mistake because the entire containing utterance is relatively complex and confusing, but I'm sure there's nothing along the lines of a dialectal linguistic community where it would actually be considered "valid".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think you are right.  But this isn't an example that I made up or that I was endorsing.  My point was simply that this example occurs among the search results that the OP found (whereas Chris Mack's answer in its original form suggested there were no search results with this kind of error in them). Like you say, it's probably the work of a less articulate speaker (unless AmE speakers here consider it correct).  But it made it into print (and it's not the only example that has). https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xb75AAAAQBAJ&pg=SL1-PA61&

Comment: Perhaps it’s due the fact that without either, as I pointed out, it’s strictly nonsensical, that that kind of linguistic laziness is used or even considered acceptable, as the intended meaning can be easily derived.

Comment: I certainly wasn't suggesting native speakers *never* make such a mistake - quite the opposite. All I'm saying is I don't believe any significant number of native speakers would actually *defend* the usage. It might pass without comment in the context of a relatively complex and distracting containing utterance, but never in, say, *The hotel I stay is expensive* (which is syntactically identical to your example in terms of the missing "helper words").